# Запись элемента в односвязный список

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Не могу понять как реализовать запись элементов в список. В чем моя ошибка?

---

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::add(T &info)
{
    // Создание нового узла
    Item<T> *item = new Item<T>(info);

    // Получить начало списка в t
    Item<T> *t = top;

    // пока не дошли до последнего элемента списка
    while (t->getNext() != nullptr) {
        // Получить очередной элемент
        t = t->getNext();
    } // while

    // Добавить в список этот новый узел
    t->setNext(item); // <- тут ошибка невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "Item<T> *" в "Car *"
}
```

---

Вот содержимое Item.h

```
#pragma once
template <class T> class Item
{
    T    info;
    Item *next;

public:
    Item();
    Item(T info);
    ~Item();

    T    getInfo() const { return info; }
    void setInfo(T &value) { info = value; }

    Item *getNext() const { return next; }
    void setNext(T *ptr) { next = ptr; }

    template <class T>
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Item<T> &item);
};
```

---

Содержимое main

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include "List.h"
#include "Car.h"

HANDLE h;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    init();
    List<Car> Cars;
    Car carz(1200, 4);
    Cars.add(carz);
    cout << Cars;
    return 0;
} // main
```

Comment: void setNext(T* ptr), лучше изменить на  void setNext(Item* ptr), иначе получается и неправильно и крайне нелогично, так как getNext() возвращает Item*, а setNext почему-то принимает какой-то T* на вход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, наличествует элементарная ошибка типизации, описанная @Vadim Shender.

Во-вторых, если список `List` изначально создается совсем пустым, т.е. со значением `nullptr` в указателе `top`, то понятно, что цикл

```
Item<T> *t = top;

// пока не дошли до последнего элемента списка
while (t->getNext() != nullptr) {
    // Получить очередной элемент
    t = t->getNext();
} // while
```

будет сразу же падать при попытке добавления самого первого элемента. (Что вы, согласно вашим комментариям, и наблюдаете.) Что вы имели в виду, пытаясь вызывать метод `getNext()` через нулевой указатель?

При таком интерфейсе элемента списка, у вас есть две возможности

1. Если вы хотите, чтобы пустой список изначально содержал `nullptr` в `top`, то добавление самого первого элемента в список придется обрабатывать отдельно.
2. Если вы хотите, чтобы добавление всех элементов списка выглядело единообразно (как сейчас), то при создании пустого списка создавайте и "пустой" фиктивный первый элемент.

Либо так, либо эдак - решайте сами, какой вариант вам больше нравится.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `setNext()` написан так, что принимает аргумент типа `T *`, а вы пытаетесь с помощью этого метода добавить элемент `Item<T> *`, что система типов, естественно, сделать не дает. Не создавайте новый `item`, а просто добавляйте в вызове `t->setNext()` элемент `info`.

Comment: Увы, ошибка осталась такая же :(
Быть может ошибка где-нибудь в другом месте кода?

Comment: Хм, исправил на `t->setInfo(info);` - запустилось. Но крашит в начале из-за цикла `while (t->getNext() != nullptr)` :C

Comment: Без кода реализации `Item` я не могу говорить наверняка просто. А так, обратите внимание, что `setNext` принимает указатель на элемент, а не сам элемент или ссылку. Скорее всего у вас неверная реализация в самом `Item`.